# all invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a linear operator such that $A \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix}x+y\\y-x\\0 \end{bmatrix}$. Find all invariant subspaces of $A$.

I know how to find subspaces of dimensions $0$, $1$ and $3$, but how can I find all subspaces of dimension $2$ (I know that $\mathrm{Im}A$ is a subspace and $\mathrm{dim}\; \mathrm{Im} A=2$ )

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a two-dimensional subspace must intersect any other two-dimensional subspace nontrivially. Apply this to $A$ and the space generated by two basis vectors.

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional subspace is the null space of a nonzero linear functional.  The subspace is invariant if and only if the linear functional is an eigenvector of $A^*$.